# Are Amazon Bedrock models quantized or not?

Tags: amazon-web-services, artificial-intelligence, amazon-bedrock

I can't seem to find an explicit yes or no online - and I was wondering if the models are quantized or not.

The token generation is pretty fast so I was wondering.